# Implementing the constructor of 3 dimensional sparse table

Tags: java, constructor, sparse-matrix

There is a class called "Appointment" in which 3 objects of itself needs to be defined.

This is how the class was given initially:

```
/*You must complete this class such that it can be used as nodes in a 3D sparse table.*/
public class Appointment
{
   public Appointment()
   {
    /*You may implement this constructor to suit your needs, or you may add additional constructors.*/  
   }

   public Appointment back;//The next appointment (back) of this appointment on the same date
   public Appointment right;//The next appointment (right) of this appointment in the same week.
   public Appointment down;//The next appointment (down) of this appointment in the same month.

   //Appointment particulars:
   private String description;//A description for this appointment.
   private int duration;//The number of hours that the appointment will last.
}
```

There are other functions which don't matter.

[image: This is an image of how the 3D sparse table they want]

So my idea was to create a new method to initialize each object (Not sure if im right!)

```
public Appointment()
{

        right.appointmentRight();  
}

    public void appointmentRight()
    {
       for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
       {
         right = new Appointment();  //trying to initialize them for 12 months

       }
    }
```

Can anyone explain to me if i'm in the right track, or must I do something total different
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i saw is when you call 'right.appointmentRight();' the object 'right' is not initialized yet.

But if you initialize it, you be going to have some troubles. You're constructor call a fonction named appointmentRight(), which call the constructor, which call appointmentRight()... yeah, infinite loop.
Moreover, at each iteration of your FOR loop, you erase the old 'right' value.

You may add some additionnal constructors like the following one :

```
public Appointment(Appointment back) {
    this.back = back;
}
```

Depending on your problem, you also can have to had more specifics constructors like :

```
public Appointment(Appointment back, boolean isRight, boolean isDown) {
    this.back = back;
    if (isRight)
        back.setRight(this);
    if (isDown)
        back.setDown(this);
}

private void setRight(Appointment right) {
    this.right = right;
}

private void setDown(Appointment down) {
    this.down = down;
}
```